# Proxy detection on public WiFi no longer works on Firefox, works on Chromium

Tags: firefox, proxy

At my current customer's I can connect to their "guests" Wifi. When I start Firefox after this, pages in Firefox have a header "You must connect to the Wifi network", and clicking on that opens a registration page.

This worked flawlessly since January 2018... But, since Monday, clicking the connect button lets to an error page that says:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to detectportal.firefox.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

What could be the problem? Bad SSL certificate?

At the same time I can connect to that Wifi if I use Chromium (even if there is no additional connection header on pages), and once connected I can use Firefox. No problem with my Android phone either.

Any way to work around this locally? Should I call the customer's IT support (but they don't know much outside of Windows+IE)?

Using FF Quantum 69.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 (/usr/lib/firefox/firefox dated August 28th, 2019)

Comment: If you have a third-party antivirus such as Avast, does this problem go away if you disable it? If it doesn't, try in Firefox in `about:config` > `security.tls.version.max` to change the value from 4 to 3.

Comment: No AV. Will try later today to reconnect with the reduced tls.version.max

Comment: @HaryMC No change with `security.tls.version.max`. But it works if I disable DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials, so the problem is likely there.